# Button short press and long press without using microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, button

I have a single button system for which I want to detect the short press and long press of the button. The task is really easy with a microcontroller, but I want to do it without in a simpler way, in order to reduce the BOM as well as some cost on the BOM, however miniscule it might be. So, is there any way to detect the long press and short press without using the microcontroller?

[image: Block diagram]

Comment: There are ICs for this, I think. Some may use an MCU. But you can ignore that fact and just imagine they have an analog circuit for it. If you are sincere about an analog method then look up the use of one-shots. This could be readily designed using a few of these.

Comment: @jonk : I feel the use of a microcontroller for this purpose is an overkill, which is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: If you can temporarily ignore the software development side (which is ornery, I admit), then the MCU ***is*** the only case that isn't overkill. Everything else is much more pain. You can take a PIC10F20x or PIC10LF32x, which come in SOT23-6 packaging, and be done with it. Just supply power and they work right. The one-shot approach is very good, but it involves lots more parts and more space and more cost and probably a lot more power, as well.

Comment: *"I don't want to do it without using a microcontroller"* -- That means you DO want to use a microcontroller! And a 6- or 8-pin MCU is going to give you the lowest BOM cost anyway, especially once you factor in the extra PCB area, etc. as well.

Comment: @DaveTweed I'll edit the question. It's obviously an error. I'm just looking for the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Define "simplest". Also, what is the nature of the two outputs that you need?

Comment: As I told, using microcontroller felt like an overkill. But, as you and @jonk told, using a 6/8 pin MCU like the PIC10(L)F-- does make sense for as task a simple as button interfacing.

Comment: @spockshr This is a very common question, finding a short/long hold for a simple PB to perform certain desired functions. I'd probably want to include power-on reset, too. Why don't you spend a little time working out exactly what would serve your needs and update the question a bit. Would something [like this](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6443-MAX6452.pdf) serve your needs if it wasn't boutique and didn't come from Maxim?

Comment: @jonk : The reason I'm asking this question is because, I'm working with HCS360 IC which gives 4 inputs for push-buttons. But, I want to have a single push button to provide two functions: one for short press and one for long press. So, I plan to drive 2 inputs of the HCS360 IC using a single push-button.

Comment: Are you sure this will shorten the BOM?

Comment: @user253751 What do you mean by this? Using the PIC10--- microcontroller?

Comment: @spockshr I mean what the question says. I mean doing it *without* a microcontroller. Also, if you product already has a microcontroller in it, maybe *that* microcontroller can do both things.

Comment: or a PADAUK PMS150C those three cent microcontrollers are hard to beat

Answer (score 2):

The user is looking for 2 outputs from the design. (Long press and short press). In my design, X1 is the button. When you close it, point A will have 3.3V instantaneously making this short press. If the switch is closed for more than 6 seconds, then point B will also have 3.3V, making this long press.

This delay can be adjusted by changing R3. In this config, Its acts as supply and model. You can use separate voltage sources if you want. I assumed voltage higher than 2.5V is HIGH. If its different, Use different voltage source.

[image]

Comment: You can [edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/511978/edit) the previously posted answer to add details rather than a new answer.

Comment: The OP doesn't explicitly say it, but they might want the short and long press signals to be *mutually exclusive*; i.e. the short press signal **doesn't** go high in the event of a long press. For the above given circuit, if the press is long, then the output signal A goes high followed by B going high after some time while A still remains high. I such cases the long or short decision can be made only after user releases the press.

Comment: If that's the case, then I would say, send A and B through a comparator. With just one input and no micro, the user can get two different inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

R3 is your delay time configurator. Higher the R3, more the delay. Adjust it accordingly.

Connect the input of HCS360 between R4 and Q1. There is voltage only when the gate Voltages exceeds 0.7V, and that doesn't happen until 6 seconds roughly (This delay is adjustable).

I hope this helps. [image]

Comment: Can you include more info on how this circuit distinguishes long presses from short ones ? Also details for "*Connect the input of HCS360 between R4 and Q1*" ? Is V2 supply or a model for the push button switch ?

Comment: The OP doesn't explicitly say it, but they might want the short and long press signals to be *mutually exclusive*; i.e. the short press signal **doesn't** go high in the event of a long press. For the above given circuit, if the press is long, then the output signal A goes high followed by B going high after some time while A still remains high. I such cases the long or short decision can be made only after user releases the press.